# FileNotFoundException - Can't make out reason

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I made a small program in Java which requires an arguments file out of my downloads folder. When running from IntelliJ and from terminal everything runs fine. The program works as expected.

When I run the JAR file by double clicking, I'm on Mac, via JarLauncher I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

The line of code which causes the exception is:

```
File file = new File("/Users/nnusternann/Downloads/arguments.txt")
```

Any ideas what could be the cause?

I expected the program to run and be able to access the file. This however only worked when running from IntelliJ or from terminal. I can't access the stack trace because if I would run from terminal it works as expected.

Comment: What command do you use when you run it from the terminal?

Comment: java -jar file.jar;
I was able to (print) out the stacktrace via a JPane - it is along the lines FileNotFoundException (Operation not permitted) 
I gave Java full disk access however so I don't know how that can be

Comment: Is it possible that when you double click it you are running as a different user than the owner of the file?

Comment: It is also possible that by doubleclicking the jar the process is running with some kind of isolation - be it as sandbox with a SecurityManager, on OS level with a different user or a chroot environment. All this seems mac specific.